# Why can the zero set of a collection of holomorphic functions be written as the zero set of finitely many?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I've been reading the first few sections of Griffiths and Harris, and they state without proof (about halfway down page 14 in my 1994 Wiley Classics Library edition) that

> the zero locus of an arbitrary collection of holomorphic functions in a polydisc is in fact given by a finite number of holomorphic functions in a smaller polydisc.

I'd like to know how to prove this.

If $\mathcal{O}_n$ denotes the ring of germs of holomorphic functions about $0$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$ then I can show (by induction, using the Hilbert basis theorem and Weierstrass preparation theorem) that $\mathcal{O}_n$ is Noetherian, but this isn't quite enough.  Indeed, if $\{f_\alpha\}$ are holomorphic functions on a polydisc $U$ about zero then there exist $g_1, \ldots, g_k \in \mathcal{O}_n$ with $(f_\alpha)=(g_i)$ and, shrinking $U$ if necessary, I get that the zero set of the $f_\alpha$ is contained in the zero set of the $g_i$, but I can't see how to prove the reverse inclusion.

Comment: For every $i$, you have a representation $$g_i = \sum_{\kappa = 1}^k h_\kappa \cdot f_{a_\kappa}$$ of the germ with some $h_\kappa \in \mathcal{O}_n$. Thus, in a small enough polydisk $P$, you have $g_i = \sum h_\kappa \cdot f_{a_\kappa}$ in $\mathcal{O}(P)$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Right, this shows that the zero set of the $f_\alpha$ is contained in the zero set of the $g_i$.  I want the other direction.  It may be that Noetherian-ness is simply not enough, and that a new idea is needed to prove the result I want.

Comment: Ah, right, sorry. And a priori, it would be possible that the domains of the coefficients in the representations $f_a = \sum h_{a,i} g_i$ shrink to $\{0\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, that's exactly my problem.  Maybe I should have been more explicit.

Comment: Nah, it's just me being slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a proof in Chapter IV, Section D, Theorem 2 of Gunning and Rossi, *Analytic functions of several complex variables*. They prove, more strongly, that if $f_{\alpha}$ is any set of holomorphic functions on $U$, $p$ is any point of $U$ and $m \geq 0$ is any integer, then there is an open neighborhood $U'$ of $p$ on which the ideal $(f_{\alpha})$ has a finitely generated free resolution resolution of length $m$. You just need $m=1$.

Roughly, the proof proceeds as follows. Let $V$ be the zero locus of the $f_{\alpha}$. By earlier results, they can shrink $U$ and then write $V$ as $\bigcup V_i$ where each $V_i$ is irreducible of dimension $d_i$. They reduce to proving the result for each $V_i$ separately. They then shrink further and perform a Noether normalization like transformation for each $V_i$, to get what they call an admissible representation. At this point, they have only shrunk finitely many times, and they are able to use Weierstrass factorization without shrinking further.

It's a hard proof though: 2.5 dense pages which cite a number of their big earlier theorems. I certainly don't follow every detail.